# What is a morphism of Tannakian categories?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, monoidal-categories

In this question, a Tannakian category over $k$ is a $k$-linear rigid symmetric monoidal tensor category, with the property that it has a fibre functor to $\mathbf{Vect}_\ell$ for some field extension $\ell/k$.

The definition of morphisms between such objects should be quite simple. It should just be a morphism that preserves all of the [structure](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stuff,+structure,+property); the extra property of having a fibre functor should not come into it.

For $F$ to be a functor between $k$-linear rigid symmetric monoidal tensor categories, it needs to:

- Be an additive, $k$-linear functor.
- Be (strong and symmetric) monoidal, i.e. there are natural isomorphism $F(X) \otimes F(Y) \to F(X \otimes Y)$, compatible with the unit, associativity and commutativity natural transformations.
- Be a rigid functor, so that $T(X^\vee) = T(X)^\vee$.

That's all fine, and this should (in my opinion) also be the definition of functors between Tannakian categories (we ignore the existence of fibre functors). However, this doesn't seem to be the right notion for several reasons. For instance, it seems to clash with the common nomenclature that a full sub-Tannakian category is a full sub-($k$-linear rigid symmetric monoidal tensor) category **together with the condition that it is also stable under taking subquotients in the ambient category**. This is particularly relevant for instance when considering Mumford--Tate groups, and can be taken as a justification that this condition is in fact quite natural.

**My question is thus:** is there a different notion of a functor between Tannakian categories than the above proposed definition, making it so that an embedding (=full, faithful exact "Tannakian" functor) $F \colon \boldsymbol{T}_1 \to \boldsymbol{T}_2$ necessarily exhibits $\boldsymbol{T}_1$ as a full sub-Tannakian category of $\boldsymbol{T}_2$, i.e. subquotients in $\boldsymbol{T}_2$ of objects in the image of $\boldsymbol{T}_1$ under $F$ are in the (essential) image of $\boldsymbol{T}_1$ under $F$? Or is this condition somehow already automatic (I don't see how)?

Comment: With the right definition, the category of "Tannakian morphisms" from, say, $\text{Rep}_k(G)$ to $\text{Mod}(k)$ ($k$ a field or commutative ring, $G$ a group scheme over $k$) should be equivalent to the category of $G$-torsors over $k$. I think this is a more important desideratum.

Comment: What conditions am I missing for that to be the case?

Comment: I think the functors need to be cocontinuous. See http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/Tannaka.pdf.